# Typical errors in equilibrium index of an array

Tags: c++, logic

As a practical test for an interview I wrote a program that finds the equilibrium point (index) of an array, basically it will return the index o the element which had the sum of the elements from his right equal with the sum o the elements from his left. The program work pretty ok, but I need some ideas (test units) to make this program to crash, to present possible errors.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getIndex(int array[], int size)
{
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        totalSum += array[i];
    }

    int leftSum = 0;
    int rightSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rightSum = totalSum - (leftSum + array[i]);
        if (leftSum == rightSum)
        {
            return i;
        }

        leftSum += array[i];
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Number of elements: " << endl;
    int index;
    cin >> index;
    int inputIndex = index - 1;
    int arr[inputIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i <= inputIndex; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Element " << i << endl;
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int result = getIndex(arr, index);
    if (result == -1)
    {
        cout << "Equilibrium index doesn't exist" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your index is: " << result << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example these are some values that I give as input:

Number of elements: 4
Element 0: 1
Element 1: 0
Element 2: 0
Element 3: 1

Output:
Your index is: 1

Comment: i had to google "equilibrium index" and what I found was a couple of exmaples including test cases. What is your question?

Comment: What values can occur in each entry? Your sample input is all positive. What is minimum? What is maximum? What is minimum number of entries? What is maximum number of entries?

Comment: @Yunnosch, Thank you! this type of errors I needed!

Comment: Can I have two equilibrium index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you declared "arr" variable with the size is (index - 1) (equal 3 in your simulation). Therefore, you only created an array with 3 elements.
And, your "arr" variable is a dynamic array. Therefore, you should try it like this:

```
cout << "Number of elements: " << endl;
int index;
cin >> index;
int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*index); //initialize arr

for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
{
    cout << "Element " << i << endl;
    cin >> arr[i];
}
// Add your code that you wanna work with arr array in here
free(arr);
```